# Given a string (created) with malloc, how to add an Integer to it?

Tags: c, string, integer, malloc

Why when adding an integer to a string, it won't show up when printing it? Here is the code:

```
char *newStr = NULL;
char *backedUpPtr = NULL;

newStr = (char *) malloc ((4) * sizeof(char));
backedUpPtr = newStr;

*newStr = 'a';
newStr++;
*newStr = 4;

printf("%s", backedupPtr);
```

When printing this, the number 4 won't show up. Why is that? Do I need to cast it to a char? If so, how?

Comment: The data from `malloc()` is not guaranteed to be zeros, but neither is it guaranteed not to be zero. The `4` written thus is Control-D and control characters do not generally have a visible representation when you print them; you probably wanted `'4'`.  You should null terminate your string. You should output a newline after the string, too (`"%s\n"` for the format string). Note that you need `backedupPtr` to be able to `free()` the memory once you're done with it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First up, you're not terminating your string with a NUL character (therefore it's not *technically* a C string). Memory returned from `malloc` contains arbitrary bytes, not necessarily zeros.

In other words, that code may cause you trouble since you don't terminate the string correctly - `printf` may well collapse in a screaming heap because of that.

On top of that, you're storing the code point `4`, which is CTRL-D in `ASCII`. If you want a *printable* `4`, you need to use `'4'`.

And, while we're listing a long litany of problems, there's a vast difference between the variables `backedUpPtr` and `backedupPtr` (re the capitalisation of the `u`), it's good form to free memory that you allocate, and you shouldn't cast the return value of `malloc` in C, it can lead to certain subtle errors. In addition, multiplying by `sizeof(char)` is unnecessary since it's *always* one.

Bottom line, I'd start with this code, and go on from there:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main (void) {
    char *newStr = NULL;
    char *backedUpPtr = NULL;

    newStr = malloc (4);         // no need for cast or multiply
    if (newStr == NULL) {        // and ALWAYS check
        printf ("No memory available\n");
        return 1;
    }
    backedUpPtr = newStr;

    *newStr = 'a';               // store the a
    newStr++;
    *newStr = '4';               // store the character 4
    newStr++;
    *newStr = '\0';              // make into C string

    printf ("%s", backedUpPtr);

    free (backedUpPtr);          // also good form
    return 0;
}
```

although it could be written far simpler with:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main (void) {
    char *newStr = malloc (4);
    char *backedUpPtr = newStr;

    if (newStr == NULL) {
        printf ("No memory available\n");
        return 1;
    }

    *newStr++ = 'a';
    *newStr++ = '4';
    *newStr   = '\0';

    printf("%s", backedUpPtr);

    free (backedUpPtr);

    return 0;
}
```

or, since four bytes is a rather small amount, there's no real need to use `malloc` at all (except for possibly educating yourself about dynamic memory allocation):

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main (void) {
    char backedUpPtr[4], *newStr = backedUpPtr;

    *newStr++ = 'a';
    *newStr++ = '4';
    *newStr = '\0';

    printf("%s", backedUpPtr);

    return 0;
}
```

or, even simpler, though not nearly as educational :-)

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main (void) {
    printf ("a4");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Sorry, I had a typo. newStr is type char*